# How to listen to Focus events (Apple TV)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

We have an interface in Scaleform and therefore can't use built-in classes such as UIButton, UITextField, etc.

This is what I've tried so far:

1. Handling swipes via **UISwipeGestureRecognizer**, but unlike Focus system it produces only one event while finger touches the touchpad area.
2. Subscribing to **GCMicroGamepad.dpad.ValueChangedHandler**
   GCMicroGamepad.reportsAbsoluteDpadValues is to YES, since absoluteValues are    needed for gameplay purposes.
   I assumed that i could figure out the relative values easily. But it turned out that when I press the corner of touchpad, get following updates:
   `(x = 1, y = 0)
   (x = 1, y = 1)`
   instead of simply recieving 
   `(x = 1, y = 1)`
   That means that there are two valueChanged events generated instead of one.

Is there any way to subscribe to Focus engine events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have acheived it that way:
I have an update loop(obviously). In this update loop I look at **CurTouchpadPosition** and **PrevTouchpadPosition**. 
**CurTouchpadPosition** is set during every call of **GCMicroGamepad.dpad.ValueChangedHandler** 
And **PrevTouchpadPosition** is set to **CurTouchpadPosition** after the Update finishes.

Obviously this can introduce some issues if the calls come in following sequence:
**GCMicroGamepad.dpad.ValueChangedHandler**(x = 0, y = 1)
**Update**()
**GCMicroGamepad.dpad.ValueChangedHandler**(x = 1, y = 1)

But that doesn't really happen. Probabaly **GCMicroGamepad.dpad.ValueChangedHandler** is called somewhere in the main thread.